# How to get ETH transaction status from web3swift?

Tags: swift, ethereum, web3swift

I did The ETH transaction with help of web3swift and Infura endpoint. I can't able to get the status of that transaction. I have generated a transaction hash by using the following code.

```
guard
        let fromAddress = walletAddress,
        let walletAddress = EthereumAddress(fromAddress),
        let toaddress = EthereumAddress(toAddress),
        let amountDouble = Web3.Utils.parseToBigUInt(eth, units: .eth),
        let gasPrice = Web3.Utils.parseToBigUInt(String(format: "%.10f", gasPrice), units: .eth)
    else { throw LocalError.walletError }
    var options = TransactionOptions.defaultOptions
    options.gasLimit = .manual(BigUInt(gasLimit))
    options.from = walletAddress
    options.value = amountDouble
    options.gasPrice = .manual(gasPrice)
    options.to = toaddress
    let param: [ AnyObject ] = [toaddress, amountDouble] as [ AnyObject ]

    guard
        let intermediateSend = self.web3Instance?.contract(Web3.Utils.coldWalletABI, at: toaddress, abiVersion: 2),
        let transaction = intermediateSend.write(parameters: param, extraData: Data(), transactionOptions: options),
        let walletPassword = mainAccount.walletPassword
    else { throw LocalError.walletError }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.transactionInitiated, object: nil)
    }
    let sendResult = try transaction.send(password: walletPassword)
    Log.s(sendResult)
```

And this is my code for getting a transaction receipt

```
let receipt = try self.web3Instance.eth.getTransactionReceipt(sendResult.hash)
```

The receipt was generated after a few seconds. how to get real-time transaction status using web3swift and infura API? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can fetch the receipt of transaction performed at blockchain by calling the `getTransactionReceipt` function. First of all, you need to convert your hash string to data bytes and then call the function.
`getTransactionReceipt` function returns result of type `TransactionReceipt` and from receipt you can fetch status, block number, contract address etc...

```
guard let bytecode = Data.fromHex(hash) else {
        completion(Result.failure(NSError.init(domain: "Error in byte code", code: 3)))
        return
    }
do {
        let receipt = try web3Instance.eth.getTransactionReceipt(bytecode)
        print(receipt.status)
    }catch {
        print(error)
    }
```